# Example of plugin, which is used with <object> element

Tags: html, element

I have two questions. If you can, please answer...

1. Could you show an example, where used plugin by object element in HTML?
2. Previously we could add video for flash player by using object, but now that doesn't used. Can you show an example, where used any resource for any plugin?

Comment: This should be easy to research. Find a plugin. Look at how it's used. Does it use the `object` element? Yes? There's your example, for both questions. I'd look at CAD drawings or other 3D artifacts, AR/VR output, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that browser plugins are a dead technology.

The term generally refers to applications implementing NPAPI (the "Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface"), originally implemented by the Netscape browser (predecessor of today's Firefox) and then copied by other browsers. It essentially gives complete control over part of the web page to an external program, which makes it very flexible, but very hard to make secure and stable.

In 2015, Google Chrome removed support for NPAPI, using a new API to support Adobe Flash; Firefox blocked any plugin other than Flash in 2017. In 2021, Adobe ended support for Flash, and pushed out an update automatically uninstalling it from user's computers, so these exceptions are no longer needed.